# Scheme: What is the difference between define and let when used with continutation

Tags: scheme, racket, continuations

I'm wondering the difference between the two following code:

```
(define cont2 #f) 
(call/cc (lambda (k) (set! cont2 k)))
(display "*")
(cont2 #f)
```

and

```
(let [(cont #f)]
  (call/cc (lambda (k) (set! cont k)))
  (display "*")
  (cont #f))
```

In my opinion, the correct behavior of these two programs should be printing '*' infinitely.
However, the first one only prints one '*' and exits,
while the second one gives the correct behavior.

So I'm confused. Is there something special done with `define` 
or the continuation is not what I thought - all the following programs until the end of the program, it seems to have a boundary or something.

Another guess is that the top-level of environment is special treated, like this:

```
(define (test)
  (define cont2 #f) 
  (call/cc (lambda (k) (set! cont2 k)))
  (display "*")
  (cont2 #f))
(test)
```

This works, but why?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8):

In Racket, each top-level expression is wrapped with a [prompt](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html?q=prompt#%28tech._prompt%29).

Since [`call/cc`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html?q=call/cc&q=prompt#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._call-with-current-continuation%29%29) only "captures the current continuation up to the nearest prompt", in your first example, none of the other top-level expressions are captured, so applying `cont2` to `#f` results in just `#f`.

Also, wrapping the first example in `begin` won't change things since a top-level `begin` implicitly splices its contents as if they were top-level expressions.

Answer (score 4):

When you are at the top-level, the continuation of (notice the prompt character '>'):

```
> (call/cc (lambda (k) (set! cont2 k)))
```

is the top-level read-eval-print-loop.  That is, in your first code snippet you enter the expressions one-by-one, going back to the top-level after each.  If instead you did:

```
(begin
  (define cont3 #f)
  ...
  (cont3 #f))
```

you'd get infinite '*'s (because you got back to top-level only at the completion of the `begin`).  Your third code snippet is an instance of this; you get infinite '*'s because the continuation isn't the top-level loop.

Comment: Actually, in Racket, even a `begin` wouldn't be sufficient to cause the infinite loop.

Comment: In Ikarus, the infinite loop does occur.

Comment: That actually makes sence. Thank you @GoZoner. As Chris said, in Racket it doesn't work, but in Gambit it works, why is this?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young, by the way, in Ikarus this `(let ((n 100000)) (time (/ (factorial n) (factorial (- n 1)))))` takes 11 seconds; in Racket 55 seconds.

Comment: @ShivaWu it is because `begin` at the top-level can be interpreted exactly like a series of individual expressions.  Some implementations treat it like that; other implementation treat it as one expression.  In the Scheme compilers I just tried: Ikarus, Guile and Larceny treat it as one expression; Racket treats it as individual expressions.

Comment: @GoZoner I think you are right about the one expression thing. And you're still using all the old implementations? Ikarus and Larceny seem to be stopped. Racket is slow we all know that :-) In my machine it takes 84s(in REPL), but I think this can be improved. Funny thing is that Gambit crashes on this test.

Answer (score 2):

It's not only in your opinion. If your doing this in an `R5RS` or `R6RS` both not behaving the same is a violation of the report. In `racket` (the r5rs implementation) it probably is violating since I did test their `plt-r5rs` and it clearly doesn't loop forever.

`#lang racket` (the default language of the implementation `racket`) doesn't conform to any standard so, like `perl5`, how it behaves is the specification. Their documentation writes [a lot about prompt tags](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html?q=call/cc) which reduces the scope of a continuation.

There are [arguments against call/cc](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/against-callcc.html) that comes to mind when reading this question. I think the interesting part is:

> It is telling that call/cc as implemented in real Scheme systems **never
>   captures the whole continuation** anyway: Many Scheme systems put
>   implicit control delimiter around REPL or threads. These implicit
>   delimiters are easily noticeable: for example, in Petite Chez or
>   Scheme48, the code
>
> ```
>  (let ((k0 #f))
>    (call/cc (lambda (k) (set! k0 k)))
>    (display 0)
>    (k0 #f))
> ```
>
> prints the unending stream of zeros. If we put each operation on its
>   own line (evaluated by its own REPL):
>
> ```
>  (define k0 #f)
>  (call/cc (lambda (k) (set! k0 k)))
>  (display 0)
>  (k0 #f)
> ```
>
> the output is mere 0 #f.

I'm not sure if I'm against `call/cc` as a primitive (I believe your tools should give you the possibility to shoot yourself in the foot). I feel I might change my mind after writing a Scheme compiler though so I'll come back to this when I have.

Answer (score 0):

This also works, don't ask me why. (Call/cc just blows my mind)

```
(define cont2 #f)     
((lambda () 
  (call/cc (lambda (k) (set! cont2 k)))
  (display "*")
  (cont2 #f)))
```

In your test define the three lines are within an implicit begin struction that you call together that is invoked at the top level. In my version I've just made an anonymous thunk to which invokes itself. In your first define of cont2, your define is just creating a placeholder for the value, and your function calls after aren't linked together within and environment,